# Catch a configuration error in Play! Framework 2.0.4

Tags: java, database, configuration, playframework-2.0, global

My Play! 2.0.4 web application currently connects to several RDS MySQL databases, with the configuration file as such:

```
    # Africa
    db.afr.url="jdbc:mysql://<africa-server>:3306/users"
    db.afr.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.afr.user=user1
    db.afr.password=****
    db.afr.logStatements=true

    # Europe
    db.eur.url="jdbc:mysql://<europe-server>:3306/users"
    db.eur.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.eur.user=user1
    db.eur.password=****
    db.eur.logStatements=true
```

This works perfectly, while all the databases are running. However, if one of the databases is down (for whatever reason) the entire application fails, throwing a Configuration error (Cannot connect to databases [afr]).

How would I catch the Configuration Error on startup to catch and ignore/log these messages instead of killing the server completely? I've looked into using Global.java's onError() override but I'm having no luck there.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  Not a great solution but an OK work-around maybe.

Copy the contents of play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin to your own file SafeDBPlugin.scala with class name SafeDBPlugin.  It needs to be in the package play.api.db (though you can put the file anywhere you want in your code base as usual).  The important part is changing the line in method onStartup() that reports the config error and changing that to say logger.warn().

Disable the built-in dbplugin (BoneCPPlugin) by adding the following line to your application.conf:

```
dbplugin=disabled
```

Add your new plugin by adding the following line to play.plugins:

```
600:play.api.db.SafeDBPlugin
```